# Как сделать "Следующая/Предыдущая" страница в пагинации? PHP

Tags: php, backend

Есть такой код:

```
<a href="?page=Что здесь вписать?">Предыдущая страница</a>
<a href="?page=(Номер страницы, к примеру 4)" class="active">4</a>
<a href="?page=Что здесь вписать?">Следующая страница</a>
```

Как сделать "Следующая/Предыдущая" страница в пагинации? PHP

Вот сама функция пагинации:

```
function get_singles_all(){   

global $db;

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$notesOnPage = 50;
$from = ($page - 1) * $notesOnPage;


$singles = $db->query("SELECT * FROM singles WHERE id > 0 AND M='visible' AND tip='Фильм' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $from,$notesOnPage");
return $singles;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вычислить в php предыдущую и след. страницу, записать в переменную, вывести.
http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=062
вот довольно простой пример

```
$nextPage = $page +1;
$prevPage = $page - 1;
```

Обратите внимание, вам необходимо посчитать общее кол-во страниц, чтобы не показывать эти кнопки, когда таких страниц нет.

```
<a href="?page=<?php echo $prevPage;?>">Предыдущая страница</a>
<a href="?page=(Номер страницы, к примеру 4)" class="active">4</a>
<a href="?page=<?php echo $nextPage;?>">Следующая страница</a>
```

В примере всё расписано.